# Which of the following studies is the most important for a penetration tester?

Tags: penetration-test, professional-education

I want to study cyber security in the future, but before I can do that I believe that I have to study one of the following educational programs:

- Network Administrator
- Application Developer
- IT Administrator

Which of these programs is fundamental for a penetration tester?

Answer (score 2):

> Which of these programs is the fundament for a penetration tester ?

It depends what type of penetration tester but in general - **All.**

As a penetration tester it is your job to know all about the whole stack from the down up.

But if I would have to choose one to get started on I think that studying IT Administrator will provide you with a little of everything allowing you to get a basic concept of what you will be working with as a penetration tester.

Comment: Would you say that networking is more important then an application developer ? ( I've already got the IT basics)

Comment: Good point about what kind of tester.  You can definitely go down a rabbit hole there with testing application security vs the security of the network.